# Store Json object in mongoDb with fetch request

Tags: node.js, json, mongodb, fetch

I have a User model and trying to add education field to mongoDB as json object as follows,

User model

```
education: {
    "school": String,
    "years":Number
  },
```

Client

```
//add Education section
  const updateEducation = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    await fetch(`http://localhost:5000/api/user/updateEducation`, {
      method: "PUT",
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/JSON", token: accessToken },
      body: JSON.stringify({ userid: userid, educationSchool: educationSchool,
        educationYearText: EducationYear}),
    })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        console.log("User education is:", data.education +""+data.educationYear);
      });
  };
```

Server

```
const updateEducation = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const user = await User.findOneAndUpdate(
      { _id: req.body.userid },
      {
        $set: {
          'education.school': req.body.educationSchool,
          'education.years': req.body.educationYearText,
        },
      }
    );

    if (!user) {
      res.status(404).json("user not exist");
    }

    res
      .status(200)
      .json({
        education: user.education.School,
        educationYear: user.education.years,
      });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).send({ error: error.message });
  }
};
```

When im hitting this endpoint in postman **http://localhost:5000/api/user/updateEducation**

```
{
"userid":"63bbe4df75dca5aac7576e47",
"educationSchool":"Test college",
"educationYearText":"2018"
}
```

Im getting *{
"error": "Plan executor error during findAndModify :: caused by :: Cannot create field 'school' in element {education: []}"
}*

Whats wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should [`$push`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) into an array:

```
const user = await User.findOneAndUpdate(
    { _id: req.body.userid },
    {
      $push: {
        education: {
            school: req.body.educationSchool,
            years: req.body.educationYearText,
        }
      },
    },
    { new: true }
  );
```